# Extract number from within a tag

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Let's say I have a tag like this:

```
<div class="user-details"><a href="/users/619/jon-hu">Jon Hu</a>
```

And I'd like to extract the `619` which is the user id or something like that.

I could do this which would result as follows:

```
question.select('.user-details a')[0]
>>> <a href="/users/619/jon-hu">Jon Hu</a>
```

How do I go about just extracting the `619`? It doesn't have a separate tag, so I figured I'd have to use regex, which I am not very good at.

Comment: Is it not what comes exactly after the "/users/" **every time**?

Comment: That's not a "tag". That's a url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first extract the `href` attribute value by treating the element like a dictionary. Then, you can apply a regular expression to extract the user id:

```
a = question.select_one('.user-details a')
href = a["href"]

match = re.search(r"/users/(\d+)", href)
if match:
    user_id = match.group(1)
    print(user_id)
else:
    print("No user ID found in '%s'." % href)
```

where `(\d+)` is a *capturing group* that would capture one or more consecutive digits.

Also note the use of `.select_one()` method in place of `.select()` and `[0]`.

Comment: I didn't realize that `href` was a selectable attributable. So is `a` the class and `href` is an attribute? Why did you use `.select_one`, is it because it automatically selects the first item?

Lastly, can you explain the regex? I thought we'd want something like "[0-9]" but I don't know regex too well. Is there another way to do this task WITHOUT regex?

Comment: @vashts85 `a` in this case is a `Tag` instance (basically, an element) and `href` is an attribute that can be reached by treating the `Tag` as a dictionary.